# How to break out of a frame without being logged out in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, iframe

```
 _________
|A       |
|  _____ |
| |B   | |
| |____| |
|________|
```

The user is authenticated on django-based site B.

Site A attempts to display site B in an iframe.

Currently, site B will always log the user out when displayed in this manner. I assume this is some security feature of django. How can I simply make my site break out of the frame without the user being logged out?

edit: after testing this some more, it seems it only happens when Site A is also a django site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the cookie used for authentication using the [`SESSION_COOKIE_NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name) property in `settings.py`, for either site A or site B.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a security feature of Django. The only thing like it in Django is clickjack protection, but that's still in the dev version only and doesn't work anything like this. It actually makes the site not load at all in the frame in modern browsers. See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/clickjacking/

Are you sure there's nothing in your project that is implementing this behavior?

**UPDATE BASED ON EDIT**

That makes much more sense. It's because the cookies and sessions are overwriting each other. It's not so much "logging the user out" as simply inheriting the non-logged-in state of the parent frame.